Implementing an endpoint that returns 100 Continue HTTP status in Kestrel and ASP.NET Core MVC
I created a [HttpPut] controller endpoint that just contains
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("May your wisdom grace us until the stars rain down from the heavens.");

Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.Body.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

I sent a request to it:
PUT /api/vector HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expect: 100-continue

12
0123456789ABCDEF

0

I got the response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcZGV2XGZvcm1idWlsZGVyXHNyY1xDZWRhcm9uLkZvcm1CdWlsZGVyLldlYkFQSVxhcGlcdmVjdG9y?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 14 Oct 2024 20:33:05 GMT

May your wisdom grace us until the stars rain down from the heavens.

No 100 Continue response ???
So I tried again with the socket connected to the keyboard (so I could set the pauses). As soon as I provided
PUT /api/vector HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expect: 100-continue

I got the response back, so it's definitely not looking to see if it got sent extra stuff first.
I have some hypothesis I want to check about 100 continue but I can't check it if I don't have a working endpoint that generates 100 continue.

@JasonPan: your solution doesn't work. I think you have IIS in your launchsettings.json which would explain why you observe it working.

Hello Joshua, I will keep to investigate the issue when I am free, thanks for your reply.

@JasonPan: I suspect it's going to be a dead-weight loss trying to fix it and I researched alternate solutions to design some other way to deal what what caused me to investigate this.

After testing, it seems start working by using custom middleware. Here is the test result.

ContinueMiddleware.cs
using System.Reflection.Metadata;

namespace ContinueTestApi
{
    public class ContinueMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public ContinueMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Expect") &&
                context.Request.Headers["Expect"].ToString().Equals("100-continue", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                //Kestrel automatically handles 100 Continue, so there is no need to set it manually.
            }

            context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
            {
                if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });

            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}

Register it
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseMiddleware<ContinueMiddleware>();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

My Test Code
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ContinueTestApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly ILogger<TestController> _logger;

        public TestController(ILogger<TestController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Put()
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
            {
                var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }

            var responseMessage = "May your wisdom grace us until the stars rain down from the heavens.";
            var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responseMessage);

            Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            await Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            return new EmptyResult();
        }

    }
}


I don't quite get it; so the act of registering custom middleware does something, or does some of that boilerplate looking code in the custom middleware actually trigger it to work?

Hi @Joshua I am not familiar with 100-continue, could you kindly try my solution ? And check if it works, many thanks.

Your solution doesn't compile; I'm going to have to reconstruct missing pieces but no guarantee we're running the same thing after that.

After reconstructing Main by adding missing pieces from the default mvc project I got it running; I reached this comment //Kestrel automatically handles 100 Continue, so there is no need to set it manually. however no 100 Continue header is generated.

@Joshua Please set breakpoint here, and let us check if it contains 100-continue in this condition,many thanks

It does. I put a Console.Writeline statement in the if block and it produces output.

@Joshua Since Kestrel already handles Expect: 100-continue automatically, there is usually no need to intervene at the application level (where the breakpoint was set before). So as far as I understand, this middleware should implement this function.
